# Friendlier way to express you paid for a person's drink/dinner and expect it to be paid back

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, translation

In Dutch we have the word *voorschieten*. In English it translates — according to Google Translate — to "advance, lend, disburse". The Dutch word *voorschieten* is used in an informal setting between friends where you pay for that friend's dinner or drinks and expect to be paid back later.

Do you say in English "Mary loaned John money for the drinks"? or "Mary advanced money for the dinner"? or do you use another expression? *Loaning* sounds a bit heavy to me. It's like "A loan for a car".

A friend from New Zealand came up with "Mary spotted John money for the lunch", but I wonder if it's understood in the US.

Comment: Americans, at least the ones I know, will understand *spotted*.  They might also say *fronted* or *lent*.  *Loan* really doesn't carry that heavyweight connotation in a lightweight context such as *I forgot my wallet so John lent/loaned me $10*".

Comment: friends don't need words.

Comment: Basically agree with Jim. "Spotted" is recognized but I think relatively rare. I think most people would say "loaned". It's quite common in the US to say, "Hey Bob, could you loan me ten bucks", etc. There's no connotation of filling out a formal loan application and checking credit references.

Comment: All of the above, or "Could I *bum* ten bucks?"

Comment: In the UK I think you'd earn a blank look if you used "Spotted" in this context.

Comment: @Martin - I disagree; amongst my group of friends "spotted" would not often be used in that context but would be understood.

Comment: If I take this question at face value, OP's *expect to be paid back later* implies that the person doing the paying expects to receive **actual money** later. I'm not sure I would call such a person a friend, and I probably wouldn't want to eat or drink with them either. So, @Ward, perhaps you should edit to clarify - it seems far more likely to me that what you actually mean is you expect *the favour* (of paying for dinner/drinks) to be **reciprocated** by the other person paying the bill next time you go out together (in which case it's arguably rude to even allude to this anyway! :).

Comment: @Martin - I disagree too. I actually think I'd be _more_ likely to say "spotted" than "loaned" or "lent". There's a very specific reason: _loaned/lent_, to me, would imply that my friend physically gave me cash with which I then paid; whereas in this case no money changed hands between us, because my friend paid for my drink.

Comment: I just did a quick survey amongst friends and family, they agreed with me. So I guess perhaps it's a regional thing? (West Midlands here)

Comment: @Martin: I'm South of London, and ["{can you} spot me some cash"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spot+me+some+cash%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) sounds normal to me. An ex-mate of mine (he said it once too often! :) was from Yorkshire, so I don't think it's *that* regional. I've always assumed that if you *spot* someone some money, you're far less likely to get it back than if you *lend* it.

Comment: @StoneyB - From my experience, "Bum" is used when the money is not expected to be paid back.

Comment: @eykanal  If *bum* is used among friends (at least *my* friends) it means it will be paid back one way or another (usually because the bummee will at some later point bum from the bummer). Among strangers, yes, it's not going to be paid back.

Comment: After reading this question, I can't help but wonder what the Dutch is for "going Dutch".

Comment: @JonHanna "de rekening delen" or "to share/divide the bill" is commonly used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in Dutch "voorschieten" almost always implies that, indeed, the person lending the money expects to be paid back with the actual money. It's not uncommon for parents to use "voorschieten" to help their kids pay for something, but they still expect it back. It would be rude not to pay back, and people often do return the money since it's normal here. If it's said that the lender will _pay_ for your drink, you don't have to pay him back. Otherwise the lender might suggest you to buy him a beer (or something else) if he does not expect to get actual money in return.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In first-person conversation, I would generally say something like "I'll cover this one, you can get the next" or "I've got this, you can owe me."  Or, going the other way, "If you could take this, I'll pick up the next one."

As @Jim mentions in a comment, "fronting" is a good term too.  "Bob fronted Mary a twenty so she could pick up the new release while it was on sale" would imply that Bob expects that $20 to be repaid.

Comment: +1 for "cover" and "got" - that's what I'd use in the first person, too.

Comment: All these, plus, "This one's on me..."

Comment: +1 for "will pick up", but I agree with @amacy too.

Comment: "This one's on me" carries the implication that you don't expect to be paid back.

Comment: +1, "cover" is most likely what I would say (US English speaker).

Comment: @DJClayworth I wish I had your friends because `This one's on me` implies strings attached. As in, `this one is on me until I ask something of you`.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I agree, which is why I included the ellipsis (...) at the end. Put another way, Hellion's "I'll cover this one" and "I've got this" also carry the implication you don't expect to be paid back, unless you append them with something like "you can get the next" or "you can owe me" – much like Hellion did in his answer. So, "This one's on me" works for the first part of the expression, and the speaker is free to work in whatever caveat works best, like "...you can take care of it next time," or, "...I'll let you write an IOU."

Comment: **RE: "'This one's on me' carries the implication that you don't expect to be paid back"** - so does 'I'll cover this one' and 'I've got this'

Answer (score 27):

There are two possible interpretations of your question, and they're giving rise to two different kinds of answers which mean different things.

If by "pay back" you mean the person will return the specific amount of money to you in the near future, common words (at least in my experience, in US English) would be "fronting" the money or "spotting" the money.  If I "front someone the money" or "spot a friend five dollars", or some such, that means that I expect the person to hand approximately that amount of money to me in the near future.

On the other hand, you might expect to be paid back *in kind*.  Perhaps this week when we go out for beers I'll pay for yours, and then next week you'll pay for mine.  Then phrases like "I'll cover this" or "I've got this one" are appropriate.  If I say "I'll cover this round" and the next day you show up with a fistful of money to pay me back for those beers, I might well take offense; the phrase suggests that I expect to be paid back indirectly, by you covering a future round.

Comment: Yes, this exactly. To some extent, one's a financial obligation and the other's a social obligation.

Comment: Yes, "spot" is exactly the word I'd use here.

Comment: Maybe @Ward can clarify this. I'm German, and we have "vorschießen" - Ward's description of the use sounds very similar. The normal case of paying back would be in money. Example situation: you're going to the cafeteria. The friend tries to keep the tablet in balance while digging for his money (or forgot it in the office). I'd then say "I can front/spot/... you the money". Usually the money is paid back at the table/back in the office. If for some reason this did not happen, say, till next time in the cafeteria, it may be paid back in kind.

Comment: ... "vorschießen" cannot be used for the second meaning: those expressions ("Let me pay for you", "May I invite you", "I'll cover this round") imply that no back transaction is expected. Social rules in the pub work differently over here than e.g. in the UK. Of course, no one will be offended if the round is reciprocated. But neither is it an offense if next morning the other shows up with money and asks how much his share is: you may deny being paid, or allow him to buy you a beer next time.

Comment: @cbeleites it's the case where you are expected to be payed back.

Answer (score 5):

A common expression in US is

> This is my round.
>   or
>   I'll get this round.

The implication is that there are several *rounds*, and that someone else who is being treated will get the next *round*.

[American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/round) defines *round* as

> 8)  One drink for each person in a gathering or group: *Let me buy the next round.*

For meals or other purchases, a similar expression might be

> This one is my treat.

The implication is the next one is yours.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard and occasionally used the term

> Cadge me a pint

Which should really have been

> May I cadge a pint?

But that's not how we spoke to one another.

The way we used it, it means something like your dutch words.

In other words, it's like saying

> I'm a bit strapped for cash so could you buy me a pint on the understanding that the favor will be returned at some time.

P.S.
I have since found it in the Idioms - By the Free Dictionary website.

Comment: For what it's worth, "cadge" sounds very British to my American ear.

Comment: Yes it probably is. But then Holland is much nearer to Britain than America. I take your point though. It might go down better in some circles than others.

Comment: In my (American) experience, **cadge** has an implication of "beg" rather than "borrow" - meaning that if the request is granted there might not be an expectation of repayment _at all_, either monetary or in-kind.  Generally, I've heard it used (usually in a derogatory way) not between friends, but to refer to "that guy" who's always cadging drinks.

Comment: I can only really base it on my own experience. It was definitely used in a friendly way between my friends an me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not forget the 'Ghetto' (highly informal) way to say it in America:

> I got'chu homie. Just hit me up next time.

Answer (score 0):

If I went for dinner with a friend, and decided that "going Dutch" was awkward, I might say "I'll get this", and perhaps jokingly or to disarm any protests: "You can get it next time" or "You can get it another time." I think it would be quite likely that if we ever went out again, the friend would insist on paying, saying perhaps "No - you got it last time", or "you paid last time".

Maybe you could say "I'll sub you this", which might imply a need to reciprocate.

Buying someone a meal is always a gift. It's very hard to expect repayment. On the other hand, in English pub life, when you buy someone a drink, of course, it's a gift, but there's a strong expectation that everyone pays their turn, although not necessarily on the same day. It's not uncommon for people to begin an evening with one person saying to the other, "It's my round, you got them in last time". An appropriate response might be: "Is it? Oh, OK. Mine's a pint, then."