# Why “daily” and not “dayly”?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, suffixes

Checking how adjectives related to time are created, I see:

- year → year**ly**
- month → month**ly**
- week → week**ly**
- day → da**ily**

Why has “day” been derived into “daily” with an ‘i’ instead of “dayly” with a ‘y’?

In the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=daily) I don't see information related to this ‘loss’ of the ‘y’ in favour of the ‘i’:

> **daily (adj.)**
>
> Old English *dæglic* (see ***[day](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=day)***). This form is known from compounds:
>   *twadæglic* “happening once in two days,” *þreodæglic* “happening once in
>   three days;” the more usual Old English word was *dæghwamlic,* also
>   *dægehwelc.* Cognate with German *täglich.*

Comment: Just an observation: this is not uncommon for forms of words ending in "y". _Ready_ -> _readily_, _gay_ -> _gaily_, etc. I guess _coyly_ is a counterexample, but perhaps that is because _coily_ seems as if it might mean "like a coil". :)

Comment: nice question :)

Comment: @aps In school (English as foreign language) I learned a rule that *y* becomes *i* upon adding a suffix, with the exception of *vowel + y*. Interestingly enough, we never discussed this exception of the exception.

Comment: @aps coyly is not a counterexample to a more specific rule: "ay" -> "ai". Are there any examples for "oy" -> "oi"?

Comment: @Tyler James Young thanks for the edit that makes the question look quite better :)

Comment: Anyone can explain what is happening with this question today? I so far got +2 and -1.

Comment: Related: [“Paid” vs “payed”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92547)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the quoted definitions at etymonline, I would suspect that you may be asking the wrong question :)

If I look at the related words in other languages (dag, Tag) for *day*, it seems the final *g* has changed into a [j]. The same seems to have happened with (Dutch) *leggen* -> English *lay*.

As it is normally pronunciation that defines spelling, and not the other way around, it seems that the *i* did the job of representing that [j] in *daily* quite well. However, as a final vowel, the *i* seems to be uncommon in English, and usually written as a *y*. (Compare Dutch *hooi* to English *hay*).

So where dæglic became daily (the final [k] became [i]), dæg became day. In both cases the *g* got to be pronounced as [j], but instead of dai, hai or gai, the use of *y* was preferred to write that sound in a final position.

Comment: A much better explanation than mine. +1

Comment: And wegen -> weigh, and weg -> way, mag -> may, zeg -> say, and so on. Sometimes looking at English from Dutch makes some sort of sense! And then you remember all the vocabulary from all the other languages it pillaged :-)

Comment: If I get it correctly, `daily` comes directly from an original word meaning exactly this. My supposition was that it is a derivative from `day`, hence the confusion of "why the `y` became `i`". That is a nice explanation!

Answer (score 15):

Since I was getting a bit caught up in trying to write out some fairly complex things in comments to @medica’s answer, I am going to write it all out in a full answer here.

Basically, there is a more or less regular variation in some words between final *-y* and non-final *-i-* (sometimes *-ie*) in English orthography. That means that when adding various suffixes to words that end in *-y*, you have to know whether to change it to an *-i-* or not, based on a certain set of rules (plus some exceptions—this is English after all). The rules for when to choose what are as follows:

### Phonetic quality of *-y*

The first thing to determine is how the *-y* is pronounced. There are three possibilities here:

- /i/, as in ‘ready’, ‘silly’, etc.
- /ai/, as in ‘sly’, ‘shy’, ‘apply’, etc.
- /j/, as in ‘day’, ‘whey’, ‘coy’, ‘buoy’, etc.

Regardless of what suffix you’re adding, these different pronunciations affect when the spelling does and does not change.

### Phonetic makeup of suffixes

In addition, the pronunciation of the suffix that you add to the end of the word also makes a difference, or rather, the *start* of the suffix does. Here there are four possible variations:

- Suffix consists only of one consonant (noun-plural *-(e)s*, verbal third singular present *-(e)s*, past *-(e)d*, strong verb passive participle *-(e)n*)
- Suffix starts with a consonant (*-ness*, *-ful*, *-less*, *-some*, etc.)
- Suffix starts with the vowel /i/ (*-ing*, *-ish*, *-ive*, *-ify*, etc.)
- Suffix starts with any other vowel (*-er*, *-est*, *-en*, *-able*, etc.)

### Combining *-y* and suffix

When you combine a final *-y* with a suffix, you have to look at each combination of the seven options mentioned above separately (though some of them can be lumped together, of course).

In the following, I will simply write the *-y* as its phonetic realisation (/i/, /ai/, or /j/), and as a shorthand, I’ll write the suffixes as simply `X` (only one consonant), `C` (consonant-initial), `I` (starts with /i/), and `V` (starts with any other vowel). If a rule goes for all types of *-y* or suffixes, I write `ANY`. (If two types go together, I just write them together; so `CV` means ‘suffix that starts with a consonant or a vowel that isn’t /i/’, for instance, and /i ai/ means *-y* pronounced either as /i/ or as /ai/.)

Exceptions to the main rules are in **bold**.

*(‘Daily’ is in the very last section.)*

> #### `ANY` + `I` ⟹ *-y-*
>
> Before a suffix that starts in /i/, *-y* never changes—it always remains *-y-*, no matter how it’s pronounced. (Even words that end in *-ie* change this to *-y-* here, such as *die* ⟹ *dying*, or *lie* ⟹ *lying*.)
>
> - *busy* ⟹ *busying*
>     *say* ⟹ *saying*
>     *shy* ⟹ *shying*
>     *clay* ⟹ *clayish*
>     *dry* ⟹ *dryish*

> #### /i ai/ + `X` ⟹ *-ie-*
>
> Before a suffix consisting of only one consonant, *-y* pronounced /i/ or /ai/ is written *-ie-*
>
> - *busy* ⟹ *busied, busies*
>     *dry* ⟹ *dries, dried*

> #### /i/ + `CV` ⟹ *-i-*
>
> Before a suffix starting in a consonant or a non-/i/ vowel, *-y* pronounced /i/ changes to *-i-*. (This does not happen in the rare instance where the *-y* pronounced /i/ follows a vowel sound; so *gooey* ⟹ *gooeyness*, rather than **gooiness* or **gooeiness*.)
>
> - *busy* ⟹ *business, busier, busily*
>     *study* ⟹ *studier, ?studiable*
>     *very* ⟹ *verily*

> #### /ai/ + `CV` ⟹ *-y-* (sometimes also *-i-*)
>
> Before a suffix starting in a consonant or non-/i/ vowel, *-y* pronounced /ai/ generally remains in monosyllabics, though there are some individual exceptions where a variant spelling with *-i-* also exists. In polysyllabic words, *-i-* is the rule.
>
> - *shy* ⟹ *shyly (**shily**), shyer (**shier**), shyest (**shiest**), shyness (**shiness**)* (forms with *-i-* all rare)
>     *cry* ⟹ *cryer/**crier**, ?cryable*
>     *dry* ⟹ *dryly/**drily**, dryable/**driable**, dryness*
>     *apply* ⟹ *appliance, (?)applier*
>     *rely* ⟹ *reliant, reliance*

> #### /j/ + `X` ⟹ *-y-* (sometimes *-i-*)
>
> Before a suffix consisting of only one consonant, *-y* pronounced /j/ generally remains. After such a *y*, the past and past participle suffix is *-ed* (with the *e*), but the present suffix is *-s* with no *e*. In the past and past participle forms of some irregular verbs, the *y* changes to *-i-*, and the suffix, whether *-(e)d* or *-(e)n*, never has an *e*.
>
> - *day* ⟹ *days*
>     *play* ⟹ *plays, played*
>     *slay* ⟹ *(?)slayed, **slain***
>     *lay* ⟹ *lays, **laid**, **lain***
>     *toy* ⟹ *toys, toyed*

> #### /j/ + `V` ⟹ *-y-*
>
> Before a suffix starting in a vowel, *-y* pronounced /j/ usually remains. Only one exception that I can think of, highlighted below.
>
> - *grey* ⟹ *greyer, greyest, ?greyable*
>     *coy* ⟹ *coyer, coyest*
>     *buy* ⟹ *buyer, buyable*
>     *gay* ⟹ *gayer*, *gayety/**gaiety***

> #### /j/ + `C` ⟹ *-y-* or *-i-*
>
> Before a suffix starting in a consonant, the *basic rule* seems to be that *-y* remains; but there are some exceptions where it changes to *-i-*, one of which is the word asked about in the question: *daily*. Sadly, these exceptions seem completely random and must be learnt by heart.
>
> - *coy* ⟹ *coyly, coyness*
>     *grey* ⟹ *(?)greyly, greyness*
>     *gay* ⟹ ***gaily**, gayness*
>     *day* ⟹ ***daily**, ?dayful*
>     *array* [in the sense ‘beautiful clothes’] ⟹ ***raiment*** (from earlier *(ar)rayment*)

Comment: +1 for this great set of rules, but I love the irony that after all the rules, the actual word in question is an _exception_ :D

Comment: There's also the situation that although *-Vy* is normally invariant (*archways, delays, alloys, buoys, corduroys, outbuys, alleys, chimneys, coneys, honeys, monkeys*) unless it's *-quy*, the irregular *monies* from *money* can also be found.

Comment: @tchrist I’m not sure I’d call that ‘irregular’ as such. There’s a lot of variation with _-ey_, though it is true that the variation itself extremely random. You have _monies_, _fogies_, _stories_ (from _storey_), etc., as alternative forms (though the forms in _-eys_ also exist); but only (or at least **mostly**) _honeys_ and _bogeys_, for example. And even the ones that are not sanctioned in their _-ies_ forms are quite commonly found spelt like that anyway: _chimnies_ gives about 75,000 Google hits, and _monkies_ gives nearly half a million.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this comes from established patterns in spelling. If a word ends in a consonant, you could add -ly. (*Nightly*, *hourly*, *promptly*, *quickly*, etc.)

If a word ends a consonant + y, one changes the *y* to *i* and adds the ending (-ly, -ness, etc.)

Ready -> readi +ly/ness. Greedy -> greedi +ly/ness. Happy -> happi + ly/ness.

When *y* is preceded by a vowel (or *h*), it keeps the y. Coy -> coyly/coyness, shy -> shyly/shyness.

There are exceptions, (day -> dai + ly) but this should be a good guide (I hope).

Comment: This works as a basic rule of thumb, but with exceptions—one of which, notably, is _day/daily_ (the y is preceded by a consonant). A more accurate way of phrasing the rule: when ‹y› is a vowel /i/, _-y_ => _-i-_. When it is a vowel /ai/, no change. When it is a glide /j/, there is no rule—you have to learn the words by heart. ‘Day’ and ‘gay’ change to ‘d/gai-’, but ‘gray’ and ‘coy’ do not change.

Comment: Consider also play -> playing & played, pay -> paying & paid but say -> saying & said (with change in pronunciation in received pronunciation but not all dialects). If it is acting like a consonant (with -ing) or would double the -i- it has to end up -y-.  If it is acting as part of a diphthong (with -ed) it is quite likely not to change from -i- to -y- but there are examples both ways. Historically some -ed words are pronounced with an extra syllable, especially as gerunds/nouns, though this is rare today. I don't know if this is a factor here.

Comment: Also consider the word "slyly", which keeps the "y" despite being preceded by a consonant. Obviously "slily" would have a pronunciation change, which I think is the bigger issue at play here.

Comment: Issue with answer: day is not an example of a word ending in a consonant + y.

Comment: @Eric, ‘slyly’ is not irregular in the version I gave in a comment above; and there is no reason why ‘slily’ should have to be pronounced differently.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I started writing about vowel and consonant endings, but soon realized I didn't have the chops to do it. Thank you for your input. It's always welcome.

Comment: wryly, spryly, dryly...