# "shyer" or "shier"

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, transatlantic-differences

My Longman dictionary states that the comparative of 'shy' is 'shyer'. However, at least two online dictionaries also give the form 'shier' as being acceptable: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shyer) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shier). On an English language [forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1395005) I came across a reference to British (shyer) vs. American (shier) spelling. But an Ngram chart shows that even in American English 'shyer' is much more used.

My problem is that I've been told that it is definitely wrong, but if it's in dictionaries then... has there been a change to what is wrong?

P.S.: [Google Ngram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28shier%29,%28shyer%29&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%28shier%29;,c0;.t1;,%28shyer%29;,c0)

Comment: How about https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shier+than%2Cshyer+than&year_start=1990&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshier%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshyer%20than%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shyer has shier as alternative, whereas http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shier does not have shyer as alternative... British vs US spelling?

Comment: The most common American spelling is *shyer* as well; *shier* is a rarely used alternative.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/164105/47827), which deals (in some detail) with the spelling variation of word-final _-y/-ie_ when suffixes are added to the base word.

Comment: Do you say "dryer" or "drier"?

Comment: I've heard that "drier" is the comparative, and "dryer" the appliance, but I suspect many don't obseve this distinction.

Comment: **All** of AHD, Collins and R H K Webster's at 'The Free Dictionary' license both spelling variations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***"shyer"*** or ***"shier"***?

Both versions are acceptable in today's standard English.

In the 2002 *CGEL* page 1581:

> Monosyllabic *dry* and *shy* are optionally exceptions to the *y*-replacement rule, allowing either *y* or *i* before the suffix: *dry ~ dryer/drier ~ dryest/driest* and *shy ~ shyer/shier ~ shyest/shiest.*

Note that *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL).

Comment: I suppose these spelling alternatives (for derived forms) differ from say artefact/artifact, whch hardly seems to fall under 'grammar'.

Answer (score -2):

Both are acceptable in the U.S., however "shier" is the preferred spelling in American English and "shyer" is the proper spelling in the Queen's English.

Comment: @F.E.: Thanks for explaining CGEL.  I have seen a reference to it many times, and wondered what it is.

Comment: If you actually [look at usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shier%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+shyer%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+shier%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+shyer%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshier%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshyer%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshier%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshyer%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), there is virtually no difference between the U.K. and the U.S. for these.

Answer (score -2):

Dictionaries do indeed allow both spellings shier and shyer. However, the spellings are not pleasant to the eye. I tend to avoid them by substituting another adjective, such as bashful.