# Comparative form of shy

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, comparatives

I've been looking for this answer a lot and people say diferent things are true. Is it shyer and the shyest, shier and shiest or more shy and the most shy? According to Merriam-Webster dictionary it's shyer and the shyest, shier and shiest. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shyer) The same goes to Dictionary.com (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shy). So does this mean both are right?

Comment: Related question, [“shyer” or “shier”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168641/shyer-or-shier).

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online has them as *shyer* and *shyest*, which interestingly does not follow the pattern of *dry, drier, driest*. Personally I think I would tend to use *more shy*, *most shy*.

Comment: A comparative of the form "word-er"/"word-est" can always be replaced with the form "more word"/"most word" if one wishes.  There is thus no need to list the "more"/"most" forms in the word's dictionary entry.

Comment: @HotLicks *The most large state in the USA is Alaska*. Sounds a bit odd, don't you think? *Charles is more tall than his cousin*. It doesn't really work for me.

Comment: @WS2 - Yep, it's odd, but theoretically legitimate.

Answer (score 3):

What *Merriam-Webster* is saying by including the comparatives *shyer*, *shyest*, *shier* and *shiest* is simply that these are words; it's not implying that *more shy* and *most shy* are ungrammatical. If you look at [their definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polite) of *polite*, it gives *politer* and *politest* and makes no mention of *more polite* and *most polite*, even though these latter forms are used quite a bit more often. (See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=politer%2C+more+polite%2C+politest%2C+most+polite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoliter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20polite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolitest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20polite%3B%2Cc0).)

The same is true with *shy*; *more shy* and *most shy* are used fairly frequently and are not ungrammatical. Similarly, *Merriam-Webster* includes both the *shyer* and *shier* spellings because they are both fairly common, and neither can be said to be wrong.

Comment: I *think* that the "more-" & "most-" forms dominate in writing while the "-er" & "-est" forms are quite common in speech. This could be due to such more often being informal, or could be simply that people unsure of the correct spelling use an alternative form.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, yes.  It is never ungrammatical to add "more" before an adjective, unless it is already in comparative form.

The dictionaries you mentioned are just noting that superlative and comparative forms of the adjectives do exist, as that is not always the case.

Comment: It may not be ungrammatical, but for some adjectives it's definitely unidiomatic. See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+more+dark%2C+much+darker&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmuch%20more%20dark%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20darker%3B%2Cc0) for *much more dark/much darker*.