# "flyer" vs "flier"... interchangable or totally different meanings/usage?

Tags: word-usage

For announcements/advertisements on pieces of paper, I have seen it referred to as "flyer" and "flier".  Are half of the people using the incorrect spelling or are these two words interchangeable like "labor"/"labour"?

Comment: They are just variant spellings; not like _labo(u)r_, which is a US vs. non-US difference, but simply variant spellings. Related: [when does (and doesn’t) _-y_ change to _-i-_ before suffixes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163806/why-daily-and-not-dayly/164105#164105) (see especially the fourth blockquote box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated by other comments and answers, *flyer/flier* isn't a US/UK difference like *color/colour*.

Both spellings have been around for centuries, and for most people, they mean the same. The usage charts for [frequent flyer/flier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frequent%20flier,frequent%20flyer&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,frequent%20flier;,c0;.t1;,frequent%20flyer;,c0) and [printed flyer/flier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=printed%20flier,printed%20flyer&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,printed%20flier;,c0;.t1;,printed%20flyer;,c0) show no significant difference US/UK difference (***flyer*** is 2-3 times more popular on both sides of the Atlantic, for both meanings).

Some authorities claim there is (or *should be*) a distinction. Note this from [dailywritingtips.com](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flier-vs-flyer/)...

> Interestingly, two American authorities, Bryan A. Garner, author of [Garner’s Modern American Usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garner%27s_Modern_American_Usage), and the [Associated Press Stylebook](https://www.apstylebook.com/), recommend **flier** for all senses; however, Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary allows that **flyer** is more common when referring to a leaflet, and popular usage bears this out.

Personally, I think that perspective is simply mistaken, as I hope my own usage charts show. What I *do* find interesting is that among similar forms, [tryer/trier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tryer,trier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,tryer;,c0;.t1;,trier;,c0) and [cryer/crier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cryer,crier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,cryer;,c0;.t1;,crier;,c0) are atypical, in that they've decisively settled on (or retained) the **-ier** version. Most others, such as [fryer/frier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fryer,frier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,fryer;,c0;.t1;,frier;,c0) and [dryer/drier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dryer,drier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,dryer;,c0;.t1;,drier;,c0) have moved (or are moving) more or less decisively towards  ***-yer***.

Thus the preferred orthography is currently unsettled, but ***flyer*** seems to be following the pattern whereby *noun* senses (typified by the plural forms [dryers/driers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dryers,driers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,dryers;,c0;.t1;,driers;,c0)) favour ***-yer***, and *comparative* usages (such as [**is** dryer/drier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20dryer,is%20drier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,is%20dryer;,c0;.t1;,is%20drier;,c0)) favour ***-ier***. It's enough for most writers to recognise and respect *that* emerging consensus - two different *noun* senses is just too fine a distinction to survive.

Comment: So *"flier"* would be correct for *"more fly"*?

Comment: @Peter: Dunno about more "correct", but suppose we restricted ourselves to only those native speakers who think the two spellings (do/should) unambiguously distinguish the noun/comparative senses. I'd be prepared to place a sizeable bet at 50-50 odds that the majority of *those* people would go with *flyer=noun, flier=comparative*.

Comment: This is a good answer because it appeals to general rules and trends.  However, _flyer/flier_ seems to be an exception to the rule for two reasons: First, _flyer_ has taken precedence as the spelling for a leaflet, as well as for an architectural feature called a "flying buttress" -- neither of which literally fly.  This leaves _flier_ as a distinct spelling for _things that fly_.  Second, fly as an adjective is slang to begin with, and there appears to be no significant use of it in the comparative form.  This leaves _flier_ as an unambiguous spelling for things that fly.

Comment: @feetwet: You presumably agree with Garner's *presciptive* style advice as mentioned above. But the actual evidence from the first NGram link in my answer clearly shows that ***flyer*** is overwhelmingly preferred for both noun senses (pamphlets *and* "things/people that fly"). The *general trend* is that ***-ier*** is increasingly being standardised on for *comparative* forms, but that doesn't really affect ***fly*** since we're so unlikely to use ***flier = more fly*** anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Flier e is a variant of flyer and they have been both used for long:

[Flyer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Flyer&searchmode=none)
**also flier**, mid-15c., "something that flies," agent noun of fly (v.1). Meaning "something that goes fast" is from 1795; that of "aviator" is from 1934. Meaning "speculative investment" is from 1846 (on the notion of a "flying leap"). Meaning "small handbill or fly-sheet" is from 1889, U.S. slang (originally especially of police bulletins), on notion of "made to be scattered broadcast." Meaning "aviator" is from World War I. Related: Fliers; flyers.

While labour vs labor refer to different spelling ( British vs American)