# Is there a verb base-form with two semantics having different conjugations?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

Is there a verb base-form with two semantics having different conjugations?

For example, given base-form "rise":

```
"rise" "rises" "rose" "rising" "risen";
"rise" "rises" "rosed" "rising" "rised";
```

the latter being fictitious of course.

Comment: There's a number of them. _Rise_ and _raise_ share the same root, but _rise_ is intransitive and inchoative, while _raise_ is transitive and causative. The same is true of other body posture verb pairs like _lie/lay_ and _sit/set_. Then there are the stative and causative senses of _shine_; the causative sense conjugates like a weak verb: _He shined/*shone his shoes_, while the stative sense conjugates like a strong verb: _The sun shone/*shined brightly._

Comment: But "rise" and "raise" have different base-forms (i.e., imperative forms). I don't mean the same root, I mean the same base-form/imperative-form.

Comment: hang - which is idiomatically 'hanged' in the past tense when referring to the method of execution, and 'hung' for all other uses.

Comment: @John Feltz Nice:) Are such cases rare? Very rare? Only idiomatic cases?

Comment: @fundagain Only thing that came to mind, and I'm not sure that that was what you were looking for; hence comment instead of answer.  What do you mean by 'two semantics'?

Comment: Your example is an exact example of what I mean by two semantics. hang-execute vs hang-washing.

Comment: A category where this may be more likely to happen is with irregular verbs that are turned into nouns, then the nouns are verbed again, for new verbs are often regular.

Comment: Now archaic conjugation of _cleave_, though surviving as p. p. adj. _cleft, cloven_: past  was _cleave_ together, _clave_; _cleave_ apart, _clove_.

Comment: ring, rang, rung; ring, ringed, ringed

Comment: spit, spat; spit, spitted as in a roast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past tense of hang has two different conjugations.

When referring to the method of execution:

> He was hanged at dawn.

When referring to any other purpose:

> The picture was hung on the east wall of the bedroom.

Answer (score 2):

It’s only in writing, but supposedly “payed” is used instead of “paid” for certain meanings of the verb *pay.* See ["Paid" vs "payed"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92547/paid-vs-payed)

Furthermore, there is a hypothesis based on theoretical considerations that the verb *fly out* as used in baseball ought to have the past tense form “flied out” instead of “flew out”, but the empirical support for this hypothesis seems to actually be fairly modest—speakers (or writers) do in fact use “flew out” even in the context of baseball. See the Language Log post “[Flew vs. Flied](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4211)”, by Mark Liberman (2012).

Comment: How rare are such examples?

Comment: @fundagain: I’m not sure. Note that verbs derived from nouns are usually regular in English, so they may be a good place to look for examples. Perhaps wind-wound vs wind-winded is another example of this type.

Comment: There are now three examples on the table, so more than enough. Not that rare. Thanks.

Comment: Generally whenever a word is used in a different sense or becomes part of a fixed phrase, or is otherwise modified, it is considered reified and has a tendency to become more regular. It's the causative verbs that are regularized, for instance, not their root statives.

Comment: Ah, just thought of the standard example: _fly_ meaning move by flying is a strong verb: _fly, flew, flown_. But _fly out_ in the baseball sense (meaning to hit a fly ball that is caught by an outfielder, putting the hitter out) is regular -- _He flied out to left field_, but not (in the same sense) *_He flew out to left field._

Answer (score 1):

"cleave" meaning "split apart" has imperfect "cleft" or "clove", perf. ppl. "cleft" or "cloven". ("Rock of ages, cleft...", "cleft stick", but "cloven hoofs".)

"cleave" meaning "stick to" is regular ("cleaved").

"creep" meaning "move stealthily or near the ground" has imperfect and perf. ppl. "crept". "creep" as in to creep someone out is regular ("creeped ... out").